# Reconnecting WalletConnect v2 SignClient to Previous Sessions in JavaScript Wallet App

Tags: javascript, ethereum, wallet-connect

I'm developing a JavaScript wallet application that uses WalletConnect v2 `SignClient` to connect with decentralized applications (DApps). I'm facing challenges when trying to implement the reconnection procedure to automatically reconnect to previous sessions when the app starts up.

I have stored the session data for each DApp connection in my persistence layer, and I'm using the WalletConnect v2 `SignClient` library to handle the connections. However, I'm not entirely sure about the correct procedure for re-establishing these connections using the stored session data.

Additional Context:

- I've read through the official documentation of WalletConnect and the
  WalletConnect v2 `SignClient` library, but I'm still having
  difficulties understanding the reconnection process.
- I'm using JavaScript for my wallet application and need assistance
  with the specific steps or logic required to achieve successful
  reconnections.

Thank you in advance for any help or guidance you can provide!